# Socket.io get values of JSONObject send by Android client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Setup:

- Socket.io server in nodeJS (ver. 3.1.1)
- Socket.io client on Android (ver. 2.0.0)

Goal:

- Get the keys and values from the contentValue the client sends to the nodeJS server
- Assign those values to a JS Model

Example:

- contentValue: UserName -> UserName55, Age -> 55
- JS Model.UserName = value of the "UserName" key from the send contentValue ("UserName55")

How can I acces the value of the send contentValue in the nodeJS server?

Current code + Logs:

Server code:

```
socket.on("push_user_data", (...args) => {
            console.log("USER TRYS TO PUSH USER DATA: " + args);
            uploadUserData(args);
    })
    
            function jsonParser(stringValue) {
               var string = JSON.stringify(stringValue);
               var objectValue = JSON.parse(string);
               return objectValue['jasonObject'];
               console.log("PARSER VALUE: " + objectValue);
            }
        
        
        function uploadUserData(...args) {
            console.log("Trying to save userData to Database: " + args); 
            
            var userData = new UserData();  
            var jsonDataString = JSON.stringify(args);
            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonDataString);
            
            console.log("JASON DATA USER ACCOUNT NAME: " + jsonObject.user_account_name);
        }
```

Server logs:

```
USER TRYS TO PUSH USER DATA: [object Object]
Trying to save userData to Database: [object Object]
JASON DATA USER ACCOUNT NAME: undefined
```

Android code:

```
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("user_account_name", "accountName55");

        Entity en = new Entity(contentValues);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(gson.toJson(en));
            socket.emit("push_user_data", obj);
            Log.d(TAG, "uploadTestUserData: SOCKET EMITTED!");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I changed the server and client code a little bit, now its working fine.

so the server function changed to:

```
function uploadUserData(...args) {
    console.log("Trying to save userData to Database: " + args); 
    
    var userData = new UserData();  
    var objectValue = JSON.parse(args); -> contains the values send by the client
console.log("JSON OBJECT: " + objectValue);
console.log("JSON OBJECT NICKNAME VALUE: " + objectValue.nickname); -> gets the 
nickname value of the send data     
}
```

In the Android code i create a JsonArray and send it to the server. Code looks like this:

```
public static void uploadTestUserData(UserData userData, Socket socket){
       List<UserData> userDataList = new ArrayList<>();
       UserData userDataObject = new UserData();
       userDataObject.setNickname("Username 95");
       userDataList.add(userDataObject);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        JsonArray jsonArray = gson.toJsonTree(userDataList).getAsJsonArray();
        
        Log.d(TAG, "uploadTestUserData: JSON ARRAY: " + jsonArray);
        
        socket.emit("push_user_data", jsonArray.get(0));   

}
```

The serve logs the following:

```
USER TRYS TO PUSH USER DATA: {"nickname":"Username 95"}
Trying to save userData to Database: {"nickname":"Username 95"}
JSON OBJECT: [object Object]
JSON OBJECT NICKNAME VALUE: Username 95
```